# SSRS 2008: Get specific row value from DataSet2 based on calculated value in DataSet1

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have two Datasets. The first is used to populate a tablix. In that tablix, there is a calculated percentage field. I want to show a different background color based on whether the percentage is in a certain range, in other words, based on KPI thresholds. I have the thresholds coming in dynamically in a second dataset, that hold ColorName, LowerLimit, and UpperLimit fields. I know I need to use some sort of lookup function to get the row's color value where the percentage falls within the LowerLimit and UpperLimit for that row. I can assume that the Limits will not overlap. Any function/approach that will accomplish this? The reason I am pulling it dynamically is to give the customer a way to configure the thresholds, (using a maintenance screen that will manage that table). Thanks!

Comment: I was under the impression that you can only have one dataset per tablix. Can you go back to the sql and add a further field into the dataset so the thresholds are in the dataset used by the tablix?

Comment: Great idea, I just subqueried for the respective threshold limits in the main dataset, and was able to accomplish what I wanted. This should be made the answer. Thanks!

Comment: ok - glad it helped: I've added the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go back to the sql and add a further field into the dataset so the thresholds are in the dataset used by the tablix